# Configuring Nginx as a Load Balancer w/ Puma ( Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

Using the upstream module, I'm curious as how to configure the upstream to look for unix sockets that puma binds to.

Will I have to set up nginx on each VM, or is there a way to link them. I am setting up multi-zone fail-over.

Comment: Did you get an answer somehow? I am in the same position now